# Wait for actionSheet result before proceeding?

Tags: swiftui

I have a button within a `.contextMenu` (ie: mark as paid)

The first thing it does is toggle on an actionSheet to select the payment method. Followed immediatly by some code to add an entry to users calendar via EventKit.

My problem is I want the actionSheet to return a result **BEFORE** the EventKit code is executed.

How do you make it wait?

Properties:

```
@State private var showPaymentSheet = false
@State private var paymentType = ""

var actionSheet: ActionSheet {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Payment Method"), buttons: [
        .default(Text(" Cash")) { paymentType = " Cash" },
        .default(Text(" Bank Transfer")) { paymentType = " Bank" },
        .default(Text("️ PayPal")) { paymentType = "️ PayPal" },
        .default(Text(" Cheque")) { paymentType = " Cheque" },
        .cancel()
    ])
}
```

Body:

```
.contextMenu {

Button(action: {
    
**// Run This ActionSheet FIRST and get result of \(paymentType) **

    self.showPaymentSheet.toggle()

**// ONLY then continue with below **
   
    let thisDay = self.selectDate.selectedDate
    let eventStore = EventsRepository.shared.eventStore
    let payment = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
    payment.calendar = event.calendar
    payment.startDate = event.startDate
    payment.endDate = event.endDate
    payment.title = "\(event.title!)"
    payment.notes = "\(event.notes!)\nPaid: \(Date().dateType(dateFormat: "EEE MMM dd yyyy @ HH:mm b " )) by \(paymentType)"
    payment.location = "\(event.location!)"

    do {
        try eventStore.save(payment, span: .thisEvent)//i - Save Updated (event)
        try EventsRepository.shared.eventStore.remove(event, span: .thisEvent)
        EventsRepository.shared.loadAndUpdateEvents(selectedDate: thisDay)

    }   catch {
        print("Failled to cancel event")
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .eventsDidChange, object: nil)
}){
    HStack {
        Text("Mark as Paid")
            .font(Font.custom("ChalkboardSE-Bold", size: 32))
        Image("payment")
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}.actionSheet(isPresented: $showPaymentSheet, content: {
                self.actionSheet})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onReceive`.

Here is a simple demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPaymentSheet = false
    @State private var paymentType = ""

    var body: some View {
        Button("Choose payment") {
            self.showPaymentSheet.toggle()
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showPaymentSheet) {
            self.actionSheet
        }
        .onReceive(Just(paymentType)) { // <- add here
            guard !$0.isEmpty else { return }
            self.someOtherFunc()
        }
    }

    var actionSheet: ActionSheet {
        ...
    }

    func someOtherFunc() {
        print(paymentType)
    }
}
```

---

However, I recommend moving logic to a separate class and keeping a View *clean*. Also why `paymentType = ""`? If it can be *not set* you probably should use `nil` instead. And why do you need it to be *observable* in the first place? You can also create a separate enum for payment types.

With above modifications, we can write an updated example:

```
enum PaymentType: String {
    case cash = " Cash"
    case bank = " Bank Transfer"
    ...
}

class PaymentHandler: ObservableObject {
    func pay(_ paymentType: PaymentType) {
        // print(paymentType.rawValue) // do something with `paymentType`
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    @State private var showPaymentSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Choose payment") {
            self.showPaymentSheet.toggle()
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showPaymentSheet) {
            self.actionSheet
        }
    }

    var actionSheet: ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(title: Text("Payment Method"), buttons: [
            .default(Text(PaymentType.cash.rawValue)) { self.vm.pay(.cash) },
            .default(Text(PaymentType.bank.rawValue)) { self.vm.pay(.bank) },
            .cancel(),
        ])
    }
}
```